# Gson: Is there an easier way to serialize a map

Tags: java, json, gson

[This](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=45) link from the Gson project seems to indicate that I would have to do something like the following for serializing a typed Map to JSON:

```
    public static class NumberTypeAdapter 
      implements JsonSerializer<Number>, JsonDeserializer<Number>,
InstanceCreator<Number> {

    public JsonElement serialize(Number src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext
context) {
      return new JsonPrimitive(src);
    }

    public Number deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
JsonDeserializationContext context)
        throws JsonParseException {
      JsonPrimitive jsonPrimitive = json.getAsJsonPrimitive();
      if (jsonPrimitive.isNumber()) {
        return jsonPrimitive.getAsNumber();
      } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Expected a number field, but was " + json);
      }
    }

    public Number createInstance(Type type) {
      return 1L;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Number> map = new HashMap<String, Number>();    
    map.put("int", 123);
    map.put("long", 1234567890123456789L);
    map.put("double", 1234.5678D);
    map.put("float", 1.2345F);
    Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Number>>() {}.getType();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Number.class, new
NumberTypeAdapter()).create();
    String json = gson.toJson(map, mapType);
    System.out.println(json);

    Map<String, Number> deserializedMap = gson.fromJson(json, mapType);
    System.out.println(deserializedMap);
  }
```

Cool and that works, but it seems like so much overhead (***a whole Type Adapter class?***). I have used other JSON libraries like JSONLib and they let you build a map in the following way:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
for(Entry<String,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
     json.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Or if I have a custom class something like the following:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
for(Entry<String,MyClass> entry : map.entrySet()){
 JSONObject myClassJson =  JSONObject.fromObject(entry.getValue());
     json.put(entry.getKey(), myClassJson);
}
```

The process is more manual, but requires way less code and doesn't have the overhead of haivng to create a custom Type Adapter for Number or in most cases ***for my own custom class***.

Is this the only way to serialize a map with Gson, or has anyone found a way that beats out what Gson recommends in the link above.

Comment: Which version of Gson are you using?  What should the output of the example be (never mind if the type adapter is provided by the user)?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Only the `TypeToken` part is neccesary (when there are Generics involved).

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
myMap.put("one", "hello");
myMap.put("two", "world");

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
String json = gson.toJson(myMap);

System.out.println(json);

Type typeOfHashMap = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() { }.getType();
Map<String, String> newMap = gson.fromJson(json, typeOfHashMap); // This type must match TypeToken
System.out.println(newMap.get("one"));
System.out.println(newMap.get("two"));
```

Output:

```
{"two":"world","one":"hello"}
hello
world
```

Comment: Lol, I don't pay attention to my own code when answering questions sometimes. Yes, Maps/Lists/etc are serializable by default but you need to use the `Type = new TypeToken<T>.getType()` statement above. You do still have to create TypeAdapters for types that aren't primitive (or the primitive wrapper classes). Thanks for providing the correct answer, arturo.

Comment: @zygimantus `TypeToken` the class is `public` while its default constructor is `protected`, in order to instantiate the object you can extend it as an anonymous inner class:  `new TypeToken<...>() {}`

Comment: val typeOfHashMap = object:TypeToken<HashMap<String,String>>() {}.type   //in Kotlin

Comment: what is the underlying Map implementation this uses? (HashMap etc.?)

Comment: The implementation is [com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/LinkedTreeMap.java).

Comment: Is there any way to get Gson to create a default HashMap instead of their builtin LinkedTreeMap?

Answer (score 101):

### Default

The default Gson implementation of Map serialization uses `toString()` on the key:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setPrettyPrinting().create();
Map<Point, String> original = new HashMap<>();
original.put(new Point(1, 2), "a");
original.put(new Point(3, 4), "b");
System.out.println(gson.toJson(original));
```

Will give:

```
{
  "java.awt.Point[x\u003d1,y\u003d2]": "a",
  "java.awt.Point[x\u003d3,y\u003d4]": "b"
}
```

---

### Using `enableComplexMapKeySerialization`

If you want the Map Key to be serialized according to default Gson rules you can use [enableComplexMapKeySerialization](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#enableComplexMapKeySerialization()). This will return an array of arrays of key-value pairs:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization()
        .setPrettyPrinting().create();
Map<Point, String> original = new HashMap<>();
original.put(new Point(1, 2), "a");
original.put(new Point(3, 4), "b");
System.out.println(gson.toJson(original));
```

Will return:

```
[
  [
    {
      "x": 1,
      "y": 2
    },
    "a"
  ],
  [
    {
      "x": 3,
      "y": 4
    },
    "b"
  ]
]
```

More details can be found [here](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#enableComplexMapKeySerialization()).

Comment: Why isn't complex map key serialization default behavior?

Comment: @AlexSee I upvoted your comment, but i guess that as the name implies, since it only affects the keys, this might have been added as an after-thought because it is only needed when you go from POJO to json and not vice-versa.

Answer (score 6):

In Gson 2.7.2 it's as easy as

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String serialized = gson.toJson(map);
```

Comment: This only works for primitve data types. For a complex type like in the example you have to use the answer of matt burns.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure GSON serializes/deserializes Maps and multiple-nested Maps (i.e. `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>`) just fine by default. The example provided I believe is nothing more than just a starting point if you need to do something more complex.

Check out the MapTypeAdapterFactory class in the GSON source: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/MapTypeAdapterFactory.java

So long as the types of the keys and values can be serialized into JSON strings (and you can create your own serializers/deserializers for these custom objects) you shouldn't have any issues.

Answer (score -4):

```
Map<String, Object> config = gson.fromJson(reader, Map.class);
```

Comment: That is the method for deserializing not serializing as my question states.