# How to convert hashmap to JSON object in Java

Tags: java, json

How to convert or cast hashmap to JSON object in Java, and again convert JSON object to JSON string?

Comment: You can directly use ObjectMapper like objectMapper.objectMapper.writeValueAsString(hasMap))

Answer (score 541, accepted):

You can use:

```
new JSONObject(map);
```

Other functions you can get from its documentation
http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/index.html

Comment: This only works for a String,String map and not a complex String,Object.

Comment: You are putting `Map` into `JSONObject` but how can you get this map from jsonObject?

Comment: @Yubi this might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720759/convert-jsonobject-to-map

Comment: @slott is right for older versions. Newer versions like kitkat are working fine with more complex objects like HashMap<String, Object>() containing HashMap<String, Object>() as Object. So I recommend Gson.

Comment: I was just searching for it

Comment: To convert to JSON String instead of JSON Object: `new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(map);`

Comment: Hi, could you please edit the caution comment? it is working in newer versions as suggested by @Luismi

Answer (score 214):

[Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) can also be used to serialize arbitrarily complex objects.

Here is how you use it:

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
String json = gson.toJson(myObject);
```

`Gson` will automatically convert collections to `JSON` arrays. Gson can serialize private fields and automatically ignores transient fields.

Comment: Note: This does not preserve keys with null values.

Comment: How does your post answer the question? It is so confusing. Please mention something relevant to the question as well.

Comment: note: when you send some value in Integer this convert in double.

Comment: This converts scape characters to Unicode, any solution ??

Answer (score 103):

You can convert `Map` to `JSON` using `Jackson` as follows:

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
//You can convert any Object.
String[] value1 = new String[] { "value11", "value12", "value13" };
String[] value2 = new String[] { "value21", "value22", "value23" };
map.put("key1", value1);
map.put("key2", value2);
map.put("key3","string1");
map.put("key4","string2");

String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(map);
System.out.println(json);
```

Maven Dependencies for `Jackson` :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you are using `JSONObject` library, you can convert map to `JSON` as follows:

**JSONObject Library:**
`import org.json.JSONObject;`

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
// Convert a map having list of values.
String[] value1 = new String[] { "value11", "value12", "value13" };
String[] value2 = new String[] { "value21", "value22", "value23" };
map.put("key1", value1);
map.put("key2", value2);

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(map);
System.out.println(json);
```

Maven Dependencies for `JSONObject` :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20140107</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: didn't know I can pass Map as an argument, thanks, helped a lot.

Comment: @Gurkha Thanks for appreciating.

Comment: @AnkurMahajan +1 for giving proper answer with dependency :)

Comment: String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(map); Greate

Answer (score 68):

Example using json

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put( "name", "Mars" );
    data.put( "age", 32 );
    data.put( "city", "NY" );
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.putAll( data );
    System.out.printf( "JSON: %s", json.toString(2) );
```

output::

```
JSON: {
  "age": 32,
  "name": "Mars",
  "city": "NY"
}
```

You can also try to use Google's GSON.Google's GSON is the best library available to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation.

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: Sorry for the dig but what does the `2` do in the `json.toString(`2`)

Comment: public String toString(int radix).toString(2) is used for String representation. for more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java

Comment: which JSONObject class is this?

Comment: No such method: (new org.json.JSONObject()).putAll();

Answer (score 15):

You can just enumerate the map and add the key-value pairs to the JSONObject

Method :

```
private JSONObject getJsonFromMap(Map<String, Object> map) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        Object value = map.get(key);
        if (value instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
            value = getJsonFromMap((Map<String, Object>) value);
        }
        jsonData.put(key, value);
    }
    return jsonData;
}
```

Comment: no shortcuts and working effectively without any additional library

Comment: The Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet() is meant for iteration of a map. Reading the keys and searching the map for each key is a suboptimal way.

Answer (score 14):

In my case I didn't want any dependancies. Using Java 8 you can get JSON as a string this simple:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key", "value");
map.put("key2", "value2");
String json = "{"+map.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> "\""+ e.getKey() + "\":\"" + String.valueOf(e.getValue()) + "\"")
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))+"}";
```

Comment: you're not escaping... if the key or value contains `"`, this breaks

Comment: you're right, this solution has certain limitaions, nested maps is also not supported

Answer (score 10):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library can convert hash map or array list to json and vice verse.

```
import com.github.underscore.U;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put("1", "a");
        map.put("2", "b");

        System.out.println(U.toJson(map));
        // {
        //    "1": "a",
        //    "2": "b"
        // }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is typically the work of a Json library, you should not try to do it yourself. All json libraries should implement what you are asking for, and you can
find a list of Java Json libraries on [json.org](http://www.json.org/), at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 7):

Late to the party but here is my [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) adhoc writer for serializing hashmap. I had to write map of key-value pairs as json string attributes, expect one specific to be integer type. I did not want to create custom JavaBean wrapper for this simple usecase.

GSON JsonWriter class is easy to use serializer class containing few strongly typed writer.value() functions.

```
// write Map as JSON document to http servlet response
Map<String,String> sd = DAO.getSD(123);
res.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(res.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
writer.beginObject();
for(String key : sd.keySet()) {
    String val = sd.get(key);
    writer.name(key);
    if (key.equals("UniqueID") && val!=null)
        writer.value(Long.parseLong(val));
    else
        writer.value(val);
}
writer.endObject();
writer.close();
```

If none of the custom types be needed I could have just use toJson() function. gson-2.2.4.jar library is just under 190KB without any brutal dependencies. Easy to use on any custom servlet app or standalone application without big framework integrations.

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
String json = gson.toJson(myMap);
```

Answer (score 7):

If you need use it in the code.

```
Gson gsone = new Gson();
JsonObject res = gsone.toJsonTree(sqlParams).getAsJsonObject();
```

Comment: This one is it, for GSON!

Answer (score 7):

This solution works with complex JSONs:

```
public Object toJSON(Object object) throws JSONException {
    if (object instanceof HashMap) {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        HashMap map = (HashMap) object;
        for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
            json.put(key.toString(), toJSON(map.get(key)));
        }
        return json;
    } else if (object instanceof Iterable) {
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
        for (Object value : ((Iterable) object)) {
            json.put(toJSON(value));
        }
        return json;
    }
    else {
        return object;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

We use Gson.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type gsonType = new TypeToken<HashMap>(){}.getType();
String gsonString = gson.toJson(elements,gsonType);
```

Answer (score 6):

Better be late than never. I used **GSON** to convert list of HashMap to string if in case you want to have a serialized list.

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.add("key", "value");
hashMap.add("key", "value");
hashMap.add("key", "value");
list.add(hashMap);

String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
```

This `json` produces `[{"key":"value","key":"value","key":"value"}]`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  It is producing JSON array,  not a JSON object.   And someone else has already shown us how to create a JSON object from a hashmap using `Gson`.

Comment: Hi @StephenC, some might looking for an example of JSON array rather than JSON Object since the top comment has already provided the best answer so far. I hope we can provide other answers related to serializing using GSON. My apologies, this answer should be posted on a different thread.

Comment: We should be writing answers for people who search properly.  If we try to cater for people who can't search by posting off-topic answers, it degrades the site with "noise", and makes it harder for people who know how to search to find *relevant* answers.   If you (now) agree that this Answer is in the wrong place, please just delete it.

Comment: @KellyBudol  good or bad , your answer is what i looking for.thanks Man

Answer (score 5):

Here my single-line solution with GSON:

```
myObject = new Gson().fromJson(new Gson().toJson(myHashMap), MyClass.class);
```

Answer (score 5):

For those using `org.json.simple.JSONObject`, you could convert the map to Json String and parse it to get the `JSONObject`.

```
JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(JSONObject.toJSONString(map));
```

Answer (score 5):

I found another way to handle it.

```
Map obj=new HashMap();    
obj.put("name","sonoo");    
obj.put("age",new Integer(27));    
obj.put("salary",new Double(600000));   
String jsonText = JSONValue.toJSONString(obj);  
System.out.print(jsonText);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't really need HashMap then you can do something like that:

```
String jsonString = new JSONObject() {{
  put("firstName", user.firstName);
  put("lastName", user.lastName);
}}.toString();
```

Output:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
}
```

Comment: Well yes.  However, the question asks for a way to create a JSON object *starting from a `HashMap`*, and this doesn't answer that.

Comment: Some people could land here from google looking for a generic solution. The above answer might help them.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `net.sf.json.JSONObject` then you won't find a `JSONObject(map)` constructor in it. You have to use the `public static JSONObject fromObject( Object object )` method. This method accepts JSON formatted strings, Maps, DynaBeans and JavaBeans.

`JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(myMap);`

Answer (score 3):

**No need for Gson or JSON parsing libraries.**
Just using `new JSONObject(Map<String, JSONObject>).toString()`, e.g:

```
/**
 * convert target map to JSON string
 *
 * @param map the target map
 * @return JSON string of the map
 */
@NonNull public String toJson(@NonNull Map<String, Target> map) {
    final Map<String, JSONObject> flatMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        try {
            flatMap.put(key, toJsonObject(map.get(key)));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        // 2 indentSpaces for pretty printing
        return new JSONObject(flatMap).toString(2);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "{}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Swallowing exceptions and returning an empty object is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Alibaba fastjson, easy and simple:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
    <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
    <version>VERSION_CODE</version>
</dependency>
```

and import:

```
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON;
```

Then:

```
String text = JSON.toJSONString(obj); // serialize
VO vo = JSON.parseObject("{...}", VO.class); //unserialize
```

Everything is ok.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using JSR 374: Java API for JSON Processing ( javax json )
This seems to do the trick:

```
    JsonObjectBuilder job = Json.createObjectBuilder((Map<String, Object>) obj);
    JsonObject jsonObject = job.build();
```

Answer (score 3):

Gson way for a bit more complex maps and lists using *TypeToken.getParameterized* method:

We have a map that looks like this:

```
Map<Long, List<NewFile>> map;
```

We get the Type using the above mentioned *getParameterized* method like this:

```
Type listOfNewFiles = TypeToken.getParameterized(ArrayList.class, NewFile.class).getType();
Type mapOfList = TypeToken.getParameterized(LinkedHashMap.class, Long.class, listOfNewFiles).getType();
```

And then use the Gson object *fromJson* method like this using the *mapOfList* object like this:

```
Map<Long, List<NewFile>> map = new Gson().fromJson(fileContent, mapOfList);
```

The mentioned object *NewFile* looks like this:

```
class NewFile
{
    private long id;
    private String fileName;

    public void setId(final long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setFileName(final String fileName)
    {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
}
```

The deserialized JSON looks like this:

```js
{
  "1": [
    {
      "id": 12232,
      "fileName": "test.html"
    },
    {
      "id": 12233,
      "fileName": "file.txt"
    },
    {
      "id": 12234,
      "fileName": "obj.json"
    }
  ],
 "2": [
    {
      "id": 122321,
      "fileName": "test2.html"
    },
    {
      "id": 122332,
      "fileName": "file2.txt"
    },
    {
      "id": 122343,
      "fileName": "obj2.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use XStream - it is really handy. See the examples [here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/json-tutorial.html)

```
package com.thoughtworks.xstream.json.test;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.json.JettisonMappedXmlDriver;

public class WriteTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
      map.add("1", "a");
      map.add("2", "b");
      XStream xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());

      System.out.println(xstream.toXML(map));       

    }

}
```

Comment: But you should cache your xstream object anyone

Answer (score 2):

If you use complex objects, you should apply **enableComplexMapKeySerialization()**, as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24635655/2914140 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/26374888/2914140.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().create();
Map<Point, String> original = new LinkedHashMap<Point, String>();
original.put(new Point(5, 6), "a");
original.put(new Point(8, 8), "b");
System.out.println(gson.toJson(original));
```

Output will be:

```
{
 "(5,6)": "a",
 "(8,8)": "b"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    HashMap<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    String[] list={"Grader","Participant"};
    String[] list1={"Assistant","intern"};
    map.put("TeachingAssistant",list);
    map.put("Writer",list1);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(map);
    System.out.printf(jsonObject.toString());

    // Result: {"TeachingAssistant":["Grader","Participant"],"Writer":["Assistant","intern"]}
```

Comment: This is merely repeating an earlier answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).
This library provides simple methods to convert Java objects to JSON objects and vice-versa.

Example:

```
GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gb.serializeNulls().create();
gson.toJson(object);
```

You can use a GsonBuilder when you need to set configuration options other than the default. In the above example, the conversion process will also serialize null attributes from object.

However, this approach only works for non-generic types. For generic types you need to use toJson(object, Type).

More information about Gson [here](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md).

Remember that the object must implement the **Serializable** interface.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
properties = new Properties()
properties.put("name", "zhangsan")

println new JsonBuilder(properties).toPrettyString()
```

Comment: This is not a Groovy question.

Comment: @stephen-c java is a platform not just language, groovy is just a jar.

Comment: The code in your question is not Java.  If that code really works for you then you are not using Java.  Java doesn't have a "println" statement, and you can't declare a variable like that.  My guess is that you are using Groovy, but I'm not sure.  Either way, recommending people to use Groovy libraries instead of Java libraries in Java code ... not a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar problem when deserializing the Response from custom commands in selenium. The response was json, but selenium internally translates that into a java.util.HashMap[String, Object]

If you are familiar with scala and use the play-API for JSON, you might benefit from this:

```
import play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, Json}
import scala.collection.JavaConversions.mapAsScalaMap


object JsonParser {

  def parse(map: Map[String, Any]): JsValue = {
    val values = for((key, value) <- map) yield {
      value match {
        case m: java.util.Map[String, _] @unchecked => Json.obj(key -> parse(m.toMap))
        case m: Map[String, _] @unchecked => Json.obj(key -> parse(m))
        case int: Int => Json.obj(key -> int)
        case str: String => Json.obj(key -> str)
        case bool: Boolean => Json.obj(key -> bool)
      }
    }

    values.foldLeft(Json.obj())((temp, obj) => {
      temp.deepMerge(obj)
    })
  }
}
```

Small code description:

The code recursively traverses through the HashMap until basic types (String, Integer, Boolean) are found. These basic types can be directly wrapped into a JsObject. When the recursion is unfolded, the deepmerge concatenates the created objects.

'@unchecked' takes care of type erasure warnings.

Comment: This is not a Scala question

Answer (score -2):

First convert all your objects into valid Strings

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("arg1", "<b>some text</b>");
params.put("arg2", someObject.toString());
```

Then insert the entire map into a org.json.JSONObject

```
JSONObject postData = new JSONObject(params);
```

Now you can get the JSON by simply calling the object's toString

```
postData.toString()
//{"arg1":"<b>some text<\/b>" "arg2":"object output"}
```

Create a new JSONObject

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(postData.toString());
```

Or as a byte array for sending over HTTP

```
postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Comment: This is saying the same thing as previous answers from years ago, without the advantage of being concise.

Comment: @StephenC I have no idea what you're on about

Comment: @StephenC "How to convert or cast hashmap to JSON object in Java, and again convert JSON object to JSON string?"

Comment: 362 people (and counting) think that https://stackoverflow.com/a/12155874/139985 answers the question.  It says basically what your answer says without the frilly bits.