# Putting HashMap<String, object> in jsonobject

Tags: java, json, hashmap

i building a json object that consists of nameValue pairs defined in a Hashmap

the issue i am having is when i invoke:

```
jsonObject.put(hashmap);
```

It adds the nameValue pairs like this:

`name=value` instead of `name:value`

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: It seems this one: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterate through the HashMap and put to the jsonObject:

```
Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    jsonObject.put(pairs.getKey(), pairs.getValue() );
}
```

Comment: that did teh trick. Why doesnt jsonObject.put automatically handle it?

Comment: @jonney I am not sure, the documentation doesn't contain any `put` method with only one parameter... weird

Comment: There exists a built-in JSONObject constructor which covers for cases such as where the value is an array

Answer (score 7):

Use JSONObject constructor. DON"T CREATE YOUR OWN since you might miss some cases such when the value is an array.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(hashMap);
```

This is actually a complete solution since it covers for corner cases such as where the value is an array. Thus, it will make it as JSONArray for you.

Comment: Hate to dig up an old answer, but this does *not* work. The OP is asking for a conversion from `HashMap<String, Object>` to `JSONObject`. The constructor you mentioned only works with `HashMap<String, String>` as made clear [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12155874/3551916)