# How to populate JSON from Hashmap data?

Tags: java, arrays, json, json-lib

I'm working with this data in Java:

```
HashMap<String, String> currentValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
String currentID;
Timestamp currentTime;
String key;
```

I need to convert this to JSON, but I can't work out how. Currently I think this is the best approach:

```
JSONObject dataset = new JSONObject();
dataset.put("date", currentTime);
dataset.put("id", currentID);
dataset.put("key", key);

JSONArray payload = new JSONArray();
payload.add(dataset);
```

I'm not sure how I'd do this with the Hashmap. I know it's something like this:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
Iterator it = currentValues.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    
    data.put("type", pair.getKey()) ;
    data.put("value", pair.getValue()) ;
    it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
}
```

But the exact syntax and how I'd then add it alongside the other data I can't work out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Putting HashMap<String, object> in jsonobject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444396/putting-hashmapstring-object-in-jsonobject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make JSONObject like below then add it to payload.

```
JSONObject dataset = new JSONObject();
dataset.put("date", currentTime);
dataset.put("id", currentID);
dataset.put("key", key);

JSONArray payload = new JSONArray();
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

Iterator it = currentValues.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
data.put("type", pair.getKey()) ;
data.put("value", pair.getValue()) ;
it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
}
JSONArray mapArray = new JSONArray();
mapArray.add(data);
dataset.put("data", mapArray);
payload.add(dataset);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over entries of your map putting "data" objects into array:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : currentValues) {
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject()
                     .put("type", e.getKey())
                     .put("value", e.getValue());
    payload.add(j);
}
```

then put array into resulting json:

```
dataset.put("data", payload);
```