# Converting to JSONObject and back in Kotlin without Library

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to convert a nested Map to a JSONObject like so:

```
    fun convertToJson(input: Map<String, Any>): JSONObject {
        val jsonObject = JSONObject()
        input.forEach { (key, value) ->
            if (value is Map<*, *>) {
                val iterator = value.entries.iterator()
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    val pairs = iterator.next()
                    (pairs.key as? String)?.let { k ->
                        pairs.value?.let { v ->
                            jsonObject.put(k, v)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            jsonObject.put(key, value)
        }
        return jsonObject
    }
```

(I tried following this example [Putting HashMap<String, object> in jsonobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444396/putting-hashmapstring-object-in-jsonobject))

I call it like so

```
val input = mapOf(
  "key1" to mapOf("inner_key1" to "foo"))
val output = convertToJson(input)
```

What I don't understand, is why is

`output.optJSONObject("key1")` null?
From what I understand, `output.opt("key1")` returns a `Map<*, *>`.

That's about as far as I got. I'm not sure if my `convertToJson` needs fixing, or if my understanding needs correcting, in that, `optJSONObject` should not be used for nested types and I should use `opt` if I know the type will be a `Map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic in your code doesn't put keys of a `Map` into a nested object, but directly into `jsonObject`. And then it also calls `jsonObject.put(key, value)` even for a `Map` (which I am a bit surprised doesn't throw an exception, because it isn't one of the [allowed types](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#put(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)):

> Object: a JSONObject, JSONArray, String, Boolean, Integer, Long, Double, NULL, or null. May not be Double#isNaN() or Double#isInfinite().

).

Assuming keys of any nested `Map` are strings, I would just do it recursively:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun convertToJson(input: Map<String, Any>): JSONObject {
    val jsonObject = JSONObject()
    input.forEach { (key, value) ->
        value1 = if (value is Map<*, *>)
            convertToJson(value as Map<String, Any>)
        else
            value
        jsonObject.put(key, value1)
    }
    return jsonObject
}
```

(this really should be extended to handle `List`s, `null`, etc. in addition, but that's not part of the question)

Comment: Derp, thanks. Haven't done Java/Kotlin before until now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put `JSONObject` inside `JSONObject` instead of `Map<*, *>`

```
fun convertToJson(input: Map<String, Any>): JSONObject {
    val jsonObject = JSONObject()
    input.forEach { (key, value) ->
        if (value is Map<*, *>) {
            val iterator = value.entries.iterator()
            val childObject = JSONObject()
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                val pairs = iterator.next()
                (pairs.key as? String)?.let { k ->
                    pairs.value?.let { v ->
                        childObject.put(k, v)
                    }
                }
            }

            jsonObject.put(key, childObject)
        } else {
            jsonObject.put(key, value)
        }
    }
    return jsonObject
}
```