# Convert from LinkedHashMap to Json String

Tags: java, json, mongodb, linkedhashmap

I'm Workin with Mongo using Jongo, when I do a query I receive a `LinkedHashMap` as result.

```
Iterator one = (Iterator) friends.find(query).projection("{_id:0}").as(Object.class);
while (one.hasNext()) {
    LinkedHashMap data = new LinkedHashMap();
    data = (LinkedHashMap) one.next();
    String content = data.toString();
}
```

the problem is that  if the json is `{"user":"something"}` content will be `{user=something}`, it is not a `json` is only `toString` method from `HashMap`.

How I can get the original `JSON`?

I don't have a `class` to map the `response` and it isn't a solution create a `map` class, that is why I use a `Object.class.`

Comment: What is the type of `datos`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you have access to some JSON library, it seems like that's the way to go.

If using org.json library, use [`public JSONObject(java.util.Map map)`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.util.Map%29):

```
String jsonString = new JSONObject(data).toString()
```

If Gson, use the [`gson.toJson()`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.reflect.Type%29) method mentioned by @hellboy:

```
String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(data, Map.class);
```

Comment: for JSONObject(), only works for a Map<String, String>! (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155800/how-to-convert-hashmap-to-json-object-in-java)

Comment: you can use `String jsonString = new JSONObject(data).toJSONString()` if that helps

Answer (score 7):

You can use Gson library from Google to convert any object to JSON. Here is an example to convert LinkedHashMap to json -

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(map,LinkedHashMap.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the com.mongodb.BasicDBObject constructors takes a Map as input. Then you just have to call the toString() on the BasicDBObject object.

```
Iterator one = (Iterator) friends.find(query).projection("{_id:0}").as(Object.class);
    while (one.hasNext()) {
        LinkedHashMap data= new LinkedHashMap();

        data= (LinkedHashMap) one.next();

        com.mongodb.BasicDBObject bdo = new com.mongodb.BasicDBObject(data);    
        String json = bdo.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem using the following code:

```
    Iterator one = (Iterator) friends.find(query).projection("{_id:0}").as(Object.class);
    while (one.hasNext()) {
        Map data= new HashMap();

        data= (HashMap) one.next();
        JSONObject d = new JSONObject();
        d.putAll(data);
        String content=d.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(data instanceof LinkedHashMap){
   json=new Gson.toJson(data,Map.class).toString();
}
else{
  json=data.toString();
}
return Document.parse(json);
```