# Convert Java LinkedHashMap<String,MyClass> to Json format to be used in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, json

I have a LinkedHashMap and MyClass has 2 string variables
I want to convert this to Json so that it can paresed in javascript
Please share how to do this.

I have created this structure because i need to store the values of of table in the format of rowName, columnName and its value

Struture

```
Map<String,MyClass> dataMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,MyClass>();

MyClass{
String fieldName;
String fieldValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Jackson 2](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library.

An example you can find [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/) (third part):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class JacksonExample1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Staff staff = createStaff();

        try {

            // Java objects to JSON file
            mapper.writeValue(new File("c:\\test\\staff.json"), staff);

            // Java objects to JSON string - compact-print
            String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(staff);

            System.out.println(jsonString);

            // Java objects to JSON string - pretty-print
            String jsonInString2 = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(staff);

            System.out.println(jsonInString2);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static Staff createStaff() {

        Staff staff = new Staff();

        staff.setName("mkyong");
        staff.setAge(38);
        staff.setPosition(new String[]{"Founder", "CTO", "Writer"});
        Map<String, BigDecimal> salary = new HashMap() {{
            put("2010", new BigDecimal(10000));
            put("2012", new BigDecimal(12000));
            put("2018", new BigDecimal(14000));
        }};
        staff.setSalary(salary);
        staff.setSkills(Arrays.asList("java", "python", "node", "kotlin"));

        return staff;

    }

}
```

To resume you create an `ObjectMapper` then you can write an object to a file with `mapper.writeValue` or to a string with `mapper.writeValueAsString`.

Answer (score -1):

you can use a JSON library to do it. You can use the org.json library.
This answer will help you 
[Convert from LinkedHashMap to json string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870584/convert-from-linkedhashmap-to-json-string)