# Pass Map from servlet to Angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, servlets

In servlet I got something like:

```
Map<String, String> myFruits = giveMeSomeFruits();
request.serAttribute("myFruits", myFruits);
```

And in .js I got:

```
<label ng-repeat='(key, value) in myFruits'>
    <input type='checkbox' value='{{value}}' ng-click='eat(value)'/> {{key}}
</lable>
```

Now I need to pass the map myFruits from servlet to angularJs, is there any clean way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work.

1.Yes have an ajax call to the servlet from angular.
 
2.Convert the map
    to Json in Java using [JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155800/how-to-convert-hashmap-to-json-object-in-java) and send the response from
    servlet as JSON.

`return new JSONObject(myFruits);`

```
 $.ajax(
     url : url,   // Controller URL
     success: function(resultJSON){
          //Assign resultJSON to myFruits variable
          $scope.myFruits = resultJSON;
      }});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, define a function called getMap maybe. Make a call to the servlet using your url for the same, using Method 'GET'.

```
$scope.getMap = function () {
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'your url'}).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.myFruits = {data: data};
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("error");
        });
};
```

Now you have to override the doGet() function in your servlet, which retrieves this map for you through a query to your database. 
Convert the map to Json using

```
response = gsonHelper.toJson(yourMap);
```

Send this json as response back to your controller and assign it to a variable defined in scope, say fruits.

Now you can use fruits in your markup to iterate through the map.