# Create hashmap on parse dashboard

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm new to Parse, they've got an amazing interface and good data parsing and storage system.
Anyway I wanted to ask how can I create a class which contains hashmap in it using the parse dashboard.
I'm using android sdk.

Thanks.

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#data-valid-data-types parse.com dont support hashmap type. You can try save your hashmap data as json

Comment: @Talha Thank you for your comment.
How to save hashmap data like json ?
Thanks.

Comment: Just serialize and deserialize your data, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155800/how-to-convert-hashmap-to-json-object-in-java

Comment: Thank you @Talha I will check it out.