# How to add data into a json array instead of a ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

What I am trying to do is add a Map into an `ArrayList` and then into a `JsonArray`. What I intend to do is directly add the maps into the json array.

```
//Initialize the ArrayList,Map and Json array
private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> itemData = new ArrayList<>();
private Map<String, String> itemselected = new HashMap<>();
JSONArray itemSelectedJson = new JSONArray();



 private void selectedItems() {
    if(invEstSwitch.isChecked())
    {
        billType = textViewEstimate.getText().toString();
    }else{
        billType = textViewInvoice.getText().toString();
    }

    itemselected.put("custInfo",custSelected.toString());
    itemselected.put("invoiceNo", textViewInvNo.getText().toString());
    itemselected.put("barcode", barCode.getText().toString());
    itemselected.put("desc", itemDesc.getText().toString());
    itemselected.put("weight", weightLine.getText().toString());
    itemselected.put("rate", rateAmount.getText().toString());
    itemselected.put("makingAmt", makingAmount.getText().toString());
    itemselected.put("net_rate", netRate.getText().toString());
    itemselected.put("itemTotal", itemtotal.getText().toString());
    itemselected.put("vat", textViewVat.getText().toString());
    itemselected.put("sum_total", textViewSum.getText().toString());
    itemselected.put("bill_type", billType);
    itemselected.put("date", textViewCurrentDate.getText().toString());

    //Add the map to the Array
    itemData.add(index, itemselected);
    itemSelectedJson= new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(itemData));
    index++;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here?why are you doing this?

Comment: What is the issue you are getting

Comment: @AndroidNewBee I want it to be a jsonArray so that I can parse it and using volley insert this data into the mysql database.Please Help I am new to programming:) Thanks

Comment: What json you want to make?? can you give example

Comment: @Clairvoyant I would like to insert the maps directly into the jsonarray.But since I did not know how to do that I 1st put the map data into the arraylist and then converted it into a json array.Is there a way in which I can do the same thing using json array.Thanks

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155800/how-to-convert-hashmap-to-json-object-in-java

Comment: Thanks for the edits @AnoopM

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way:

```
JSONArray jRootArray = new JSONArray();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            JSONObject jInnerObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jInnerObject.put(String.valueOf(i), "Hello "+i);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            jRootArray.put(jInnerObject);
        }

        Log.i("JRootArray", jRootArray.toString());
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: can you elaborate I would like to try this.

Comment: @user3295583, you have to put your key and value in your json object and after filling data you have put json object into json array.

Comment: @HirenPatel please check the below code how can i use your code in this scenario.Even I am trying to do something very similar.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private Map<String, String> itemselected = new HashMap<>();   

private void selectedItems() {

    JSONArray itemSelectedJson = new JSONArray();

    // Retrieve all keys
    Set<String> keys = itemselected.keySet(); 

    // Add items to JSONArray as JSONObjects
    for(String key : keys) {
        itemSelectedJson.put(
            new JSONObject().put(key, itemselected.get(key))
        );
    }
}
```

This way, you won't have to pass by an `ArrayList` to fill your `JSONArray`. Then, you can get your **JSON string** simply by calling the `toString()` method on the JSON array:

```
String jsonString = itemSelectedJson.toString();
```

Comment: can you please elaborate i would like to try this code.Thanks

Comment: Yes I would be using the volley library for that.

Comment: The thing is, I've never used Volley or even Retrofit before, so you need to tell me exactly what you have to do to send a successful request to Volley.

Comment: I am new to programming so I am trying to follow this blog. https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-post-request-tutorial/

Comment: I see that there is a `getParams()` method that is already defined to append parameters to your **Volley request**, where they return a **Map**. I think you should do the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96348/discussion-between-user3295583-and-jdev).