# Convert the groovy map's key value pair to JSON array elements

Tags: arrays, json, groovy

How to take in key/value pair values of groovy map and loop into JSON array elements in groovy?.

For example:

**Input**:

def childmap = ["data1": "123", "data2": "234", "data3": "456"]

def childmap2= ["data4": "123", "data5": "234", "data6": "456","date7":"676"]

def parentmap=          ["Key1":"Value1","Key2":"Value2","Key3":childmap,"key4":childmap2]

**Expected JSON Output**:

```
{
 "Json":{
   "Key1":"Value1",
   "Key2":"Value2"
   "key3":[
      {
         "Name": "data1",
         "ID": "123"
      },
      {
         "Name": "data2",
         "ID": "234"
      },
      {
          "Name": "data3",
          "ID": "456"
      }
   ],
  "key4":[
      {
         "Name": "data4",
         "ID": "123"
      },
      {
         "Name": "data5",
         "ID": "123"
      },
      {
         "Name": "data6",
         "ID": "234"
      },
      {
          "Name": "data7",
          "ID": "456"
      }
   ]
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert hashmap to json object in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155800/how-to-convert-hashmap-to-json-object-in-java)

Comment: A Map gets converted to JSON map and not JSON array.To do this first convert map to list of map with key-value pairs as needed in question. Then call new JSONObject(list);

Comment: You could show what you've tried...

Comment: new JSONObject(map); converts all the elements into map. but i need key and value to be stored in the array elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for your example. This won't work if you've got deeper nesting.

```
def newmap = parentmap.collectEntries { key, value ->
    [key, (value instanceof Map) ? value.collect {key2, value2 -> [Name: key2, ID: value2]} : value]}


def builder = new JsonBuilder([Json : newmap])
println builder.toPrettyString()
```

Comment: It seems I've got a reading problem today. Now the code produces the output from your example... I promise :)

Comment: Well.. What if i wanna have to work it for deeper nesting,, Is there any code change for it