# ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> to JSON object Java

Tags: java

I want to create a String as follows.

```
[{ "Name":"David",
    "Age":"30"
  },
  {"Name":"Max",
   "Age":"20"
  }
]
```

How can we create this string using `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>` and JSON in Java?

Comment: This link will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155800/how-to-convert-hashmap-to-json-object-in-java

Comment: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html is not working. Could you please explain a little bit? I am new to java. I have ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> with all data. I just want to prepare a JSON string from that as above. Also note that there is no JSON key

Comment: @creative Pro did you tried my solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try as below

```
public String listmap_to_json_string(List<HashMap<String, String>> list)
{       
    JSONArray json_arr=new JSONArray();
    for (Map<String, String> map : list) {
        JSONObject json_obj=new JSONObject();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
            try {
                json_obj.put(key,value);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                           
        }
        json_arr.put(json_obj);
    }
    return json_arr.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[My JSON library](https://www.nayuki.io/page/json-library-java) fits your use case exactly. For example:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> outer = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

HashMap<String,String> inner = new HashMap<String,String>();
inner.put("Name", "David");
inner.put("Age", "30");
outer.add(inner);

inner = new HashMap<String,String>();
inner.put("Name", "Max");
inner.put("Age", "20");
outer.add(inner);

//----------

import io.nayuki.json.Json;
String jsonText = Json.serialize(outer);
System.out.println(jsonText);
```

Output text:

```
[{"Age": "30", "Name": "David"}, {"Age": "20", "Name": "Max"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `Jackson Mapper` You can read some [tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson/) about it.
You can write code, using Jackson in this manner:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(listOfMap);
```