# Display properties file elements as a json array

Tags: java, properties

I want to display what I have the properties file as a json array:
Here's my java code:

```
props.setProperty("Info1", "stack1");
props.setProperty("Info2", "stack2");
```

What I got in properties file:

```
 Info1=stack1
 Info2=stack2
```

Here's what want to get

```
var Obj =  {}
Obj.dataset= [{ "Info1":"stack1" },{ "Info2"="stack2"}];
```

I tried with Gson and JsonObject but in vain.
What should I do please?
It's not a duplicate question because I am using properties class and the suggested answers that I have already tried didn't work.

Comment: Try with a map: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155800/how-to-convert-hashmap-to-json-object-in-java

Answer (score 3):

You can loop over properties and add the key/value to a Json Array as below:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("Info1", "stack1");
props.setProperty("Info2", "stack2");

Enumeration e = props.propertyNames();
JsonArray  jsonArray = new JSONArray();

while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
    String key = (String) e.nextElement();
    String value = props.getProperty(key);

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put(key, value);

    jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
}

System.out.println(jsonArray.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with `jackson` and its [ObjectMapper](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.codehaus.jackson%7Cjackson-mapper-asl%7C1.9.13%7Cjar) like this:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("Info1", "stack1");
props.setProperty("Info2", "stack2");

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
mapper.writeValue(writer, props);
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

**Output:**

```
{"Info2":"stack2","Info1":"stack1"}
```

Here is a good tutorial about [Jackson](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson/index.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following:

```java
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("Info1", "stack1");
    props.setProperty("Info2", "stack2");
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    Map map = new HashMap();

    Iterator iter = props.keySet().iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) iter.next();
        String value = props.getProperty(key);
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    array.put(map);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
        System.out.println(obj.toString());
    }
```