# How to Pass the hashmap value from a java file to Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, hashmap, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to retrieve the value from DataBase using Java File and storing it to HashMap. Please find the below code (Sample.java):

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Sample {

 static Connection conn;
 static PreparedStatement stmt;
 static ResultSet rs;
 String sql;
 static String project="Project1";
 public static HashMap< String, String> map = new HashMap< String, String>();
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{  

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309/graphvalue","root","root");
        stmt=conn.prepareStatement("select * from TestCase where ProjectName= ?");
        stmt.setString(1,project);
        rs=stmt.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"  "+rs.getInt(2)+"  "+rs.getInt(3)+" "+rs.getInt(4)+" "+rs.getInt(5));
        map.put("ProjectName", rs.getString(1));
        map.put("Total TestCase", String.valueOf(rs.getInt(2)));
        map.put("TestCase Executed", String.valueOf(rs.getInt(3)));
        map.put("Failed TestCase", String.valueOf(rs.getInt(4)));
        map.put("TestCase Not Executed", String.valueOf(rs.getInt(5)));
        System.out.println("ProjectName  "+map.get("ProjectName"));

        }
        conn.close();
        }
    catch(Exception e)
        { System.out.println(e);}
}

}
```

Please find the below data which I am retrieving from the databse:

```
ProjectName TotalTestCase TestCaseExecuted TestCaseFailed TestCaseNotExecuted    
 Project1       50              30              8                20
```

I want to pass this value to Javascript and so that I am able to draw a chart using these values. Please find my HTML/Javascript code below (test.html):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<select id="ChartType" name="ChartType" onchange="drawChart()">
<option value = "PieChart">Select Chart Type
 <option value="PieChart">PieChart
 <option value="Histogram">Histogram
 <option value="LineChart">LineChart
 <option value="BarChart">BarChart
</select>
<div id="chart_div" style="border: solid 2px #000000;"></div>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var row = [];
var temp;
var stri;
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(getValues);
     function getValues() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        stri = xmlhttp.responseText;
            drawChart();
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "sample.java", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    str = stri.split(",");

        // How to call the value from java file so that I will be able to draw the below graph by passing the value.

    data.addRows(row);
    var a = document.getElementById("ChartType").value;
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "You selected: " + a;
    var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300
                   };
    var chart = new google.visualization[document.getElementById("ChartType").value](document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know how to proceed or if anyone have any other example. Please share it with me. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

1. You can [convert your map to `JSON`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12155874/2815219). Instead of this
   *HelloWorld* class, you can convert it into a service that returns this `JSON

   ```
   import java.sql.*;
   import java.util.HashMap;

   public class Sample {
       static Connection conn;
       static PreparedStatement stmt;
       static ResultSet rs;
       String sql;
       static String project = "Project1";
       public static HashMap < String, String > map = new HashMap < String, String > ();

       //Notice how your main class is now converted into a service
       public static String getProjects() {

           try {

               Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
               conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309/graphvalue", "root", "root");
               stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from TestCase where ProjectName= ?");
               stmt.setString(1, project);
               rs = stmt.executeQuery();
               while (rs.next()) {
                   System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + "  " + rs.getInt(2) + "  " + rs.getInt(3) + " " + rs.getInt(4) + " " +
                       rs.getInt(5));
                   map.put("ProjectName", rs.getString(1));
                   map.put("Total TestCase", String.valueOf(rs.getInt(2)));
                   map.put("TestCase Executed", String.valueOf(rs.getInt(3)));
                   map.put("Failed TestCase", String.valueOf(rs.getInt(4)));
                   map.put("TestCase Not Executed", String.valueOf(rs.getInt(5)));
                   System.out.println("ProjectName  " + map.get("ProjectName"));

                   /*______________ NEW CODE ______________*/
                   JSONObject resultMap = new JSONObject(map);
                   return resultMap.toString();
               }

           } catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.println(e);
           } finally {
               conn.close();
           }
           return "";
       }

   }
   ```
2. Now convert your `test.html` to `test.jsp` and call that service
   that we've created in previous step and output the resultant `JSON`
   into a javascript variable.

   **test.jsp**

   ```
   <%@page import="com.path.to.Sample"%>
   <html>
       <head>
           <script>
               <!-- call that service and output that json into a javascript variable -->
               var resultantJSON = <%= Sample.getProjects() %>

               <!-- Now all that's left is to parse that json  -->
               var projects = JSON.parse(resultantJSON);

           </script>
       </head>
       <body>
           ...
           ...
       </body>
   </html>
   ```

   Now all your results that you fetched from your database are in `projects` variable in `Test.jsp`. You can use them like conventional `javascript` object in your jsp file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the Java code accessable via http. There are several ways to do this. You can implement a servlet which retrieves the http request and can send data back as httpresponse. Search for a tutorial on java servlet, e.g. like this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm

You could also use a java rest service to supply the information. Search for java rest tutorial, e.g. like this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html