# json not valid, quote and backslash

Tags: java, json

I been trying to solve this issue for quite a while now but i don't seem to have anymore route to take.

I had some backslash that i managed to remove with replace("\", "") but i still have some Quotation Mark like this one ---> " just in the beginning of my map and I don't have any idea how it gets there.

Here is my code:

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
            JsonArray ingredList = new JsonArray();
            Map<String, String> ingredientAsMap = new HashMap<>();
            JsonArray prepTime = new JsonArray();
            Map<String, String> prepTimeAsMap = new HashMap<>();
            JsonArray cookTime = new JsonArray();
            Map<String, String> cookTimeAsMap = new HashMap<>();

            obj.addProperty("Recipe Name", textField1.getText().toString());
            for (int r = 0; r < model.getRowCount(); r++) {
                ingredientAsMap.put("Ingredient", model.getValueAt(r, 0).toString());
                ingredientAsMap.put("Measure", model.getValueAt(r, 1).toString());
                ingredientAsMap.put("Quantity", model.getValueAt(r, 2).toString());
                ingredList.add(String.valueOf(ingredientAsMap));
            }

            obj.addProperty("Ingredients Lists", String.valueOf(ingredList));
            obj.addProperty("Preparation", editorPane1.getText().toString());
            prepTimeAsMap.put("Hours", spinner3.getValue().toString());
            prepTimeAsMap.put("Mins", spinner2.getValue().toString());
            prepTime.add(String.valueOf(prepTimeAsMap));
            obj.addProperty("Preparation Time", String.valueOf(prepTime));

            cookTimeAsMap.put("Hours", spinner1.getValue().toString());
            cookTimeAsMap.put("Mins", spinner4.getValue().toString());
            cookTime.add(String.valueOf(cookTimeAsMap));
            obj.addProperty("Cooking Time", String.valueOf(cookTime));

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
            String json = gson.toJson(obj).replace("\\", "");
            try{
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\" + textField1.getText().toString() + ".json");
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);

                bw.write(json);
                bw.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println(json);
            //System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\" + textField1.getText().toString() + ".json");
        }
```

Here is the output I get when my form is filled:

```
    {
  "Recipe Name": "Test",
  "Ingredients Lists": "["{Ingredient=Ingredient0, Measure=ml, Quantity=0}","{Ingredient=Ingredient1, Measure=ml, Quantity=0}"]",
  "Preparation": "This is a test.",
  "Preparation Time": "["{Hours=0, Mins=0}"]",
  "Cooking Time": "["{Hours=0, Mins=0}"]"
    }
```

Notice the " before the [ in Ingredient List, Preparation Time and Cooking Time. How do I get rid of them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue starts with lines like these

```
obj.addProperty("Ingredients Lists", String.valueOf(ingredList));
obj.addProperty("Preparation Time", String.valueOf(prepTime));
```

For the HashMaps, refer **[How to convert hashmap to JSON object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155800/how-to-convert-hashmap-to-json-object-in-java)** (not the accepted one, but the Gson answer)

Similarly, for the JSONArray, you don't need to `String.value` them. Just add directly. From the API, use the [**`add(String name, JsonElement element)`**](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html) method.

```
obj.add("Preparation Time", prepTime);
```

---

**Detailed answer**

Stop string replacing. Your internal data sets are just not JSON, so you are building that JSON incorrectly.

Notice the syntax highlighting

Invalid

```
{ "Preparation Time": "["{Hours=0, Mins=0}"]" }
```

Valid - The inner string is escaped.

```
{ "Preparation Time": "[\"{Hours=0, Mins=0}\"]" }
```

Which is essentially seen as this to any JSON parser

```
{ "Preparation Time": "..." }
```

---

You can `getString("Preparation Time")`, and it returns `"[\"{Hours=0, Mins=0}\"]"` as a String. If you convert that to a `JSONArray`, then it's an array of strings.  Print the first element, you should only see `"{Hours=0, Mins=0}"` (quotes are kept), and so you should be replacing the quotes and `{}` characters, not the backslashes. And you could split on equal signs to get key-values, and etc,etc... but that sounds like a lot of work.

---

Basically, there are no equal signs in key-value JSON pairs.

```
{Ingredient=Ingredient0, Measure=ml, Quantity=0}
```

So, Gson is doing to treat every single one of those keys's values as `String` type and any quotes or backslashes are going to be unescaped when you *print the data*, but it is stored in memory *escaped*.

However you want to parse the extra data is unrelated to JSON parsing, so that is my hint and you can stop scratching your head hopefully.

---

For what it's worth, here **is** JSON for that data. So, my suggestion is to fix the model class and pieces of code that generate this data.

```
{
    "Recipe Name": "Test",
    "Ingredients Lists": [{
        "Ingredient": "Ingredient0",
        "Measure": "ml",
        "Quantity": 0
    }, {
        "Ingredient": "Ingredient1",
        "Measure": "ml",
        "Quantity": 0
    }],
    "Preparation": "This is a test.",
    "Preparation Time": [{
        "Hours": 0,
        "Mins": 0
    }],
    "Cooking Time": [{
        "Hours": 0,
        "Mins": 0
    }]
}
```

Comment: Use `add(String property, JsonElement value)`