# How convert hashmap values containing object into JSON file and back to Objects in Java ?

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist, hashmap

The object that is stored in the hashmap, is a connector object that connects 2 other classes into one. One of this class has arraylist of another class.

How do I make this hashmap into a JSON object. I tried with Jackson but still failed to accomplish this. Anyone has any idea of getting this done?

Comment: The correct way to ask this question would be: I'm trying to marshal and unmarshal a Map to JSON using this code : <code>. Here are the classes of the objects stored in the map: <code>. I get this exception: <complete stack trace>. What is the reason? How to fix this code?

Comment: Also read this guide: [minimum complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert hashmap to JSON object in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155800/how-to-convert-hashmap-to-json-object-in-java)

Comment: @Nishant This is not a duplicate of the question you posted.