# Converting a hash map to json in android

Tags: java, gson

I have collection where I am able to convert to a json value

```
Map<String,String> mSizes
```

Here I am converting to json using and its working

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
mStruct = gson.toJson(mSizes);
```

---

I have another Collection

```
 Map<String,Map<String,String>> mSizesNested;
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 mStruct = gson.toJson(mSizesNested);
```

Here I am getting `{}`, How to resolve this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert hashmap to JSON object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155800/how-to-convert-hashmap-to-json-object-in-java)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
JSONObject mapToObject = new JSONObject(mSizes);
```

It can only work for the `Map<String, String>`

Comment: refer this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155800/how-to-convert-hashmap-to-json-object-in-java

Answer (score 0):

> only this your doing wrong is your just calling the Gson class you have to call the GsonBuilder instead .

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
String json = gson.toJson(mSizesNested);
```

Comment: Since when do you need the builder to create a `Gson` instance? Please show some evidence that this is necessary.

Comment: The primary class to use is **Gson** which you can just create by calling new Gson(). There is also a class **GsonBuilder** available that can be used to create a Gson instance with various settings like version control and so on. 
Moreover GsonBuilder is use when we need to make  Custom Serialization and Deserialization .
Hope that answer your question for more [link](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

Comment: In your snippet, you're not configuring **any** custom serialization/deserialization, so it's unclear why you're suggesting they use the `GsonBuilder` at all. Your answer also suggests that's the entire issue, the use of `Gson` instead of instantiating it through `GsonBuilder` which is entirely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of converting a Map to json
is

```
new JSONObject(map);
```

Now your question is about converting

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> mSizesNested;
```

to json 
first convert every msize map to jsonobject
then map

`Map<String,Map<String,jsonobject.toString>> mSizesNested;`

Hope this helps.