# Converting Map to JSONObject

Tags: java, json

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

    HashMap<String,String> testAttMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        HashMap<String,String> jsonMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        jsonMap.put("containerType", "Drive");
        testAttMap.put("idNbr", "11111111111");
        testAttMap.put("name", "ATTTT");
        jsonMap.put("testAtts", new JSONObject(testAttMap).toString());
        System.out.println(new JSONArray().put(jsonMap));
```

Expecting :

```
[{"containerType":"Drive","testAtts":"{"idNbr":"11111111111","name":"ATTTT"}"}]
```

Actual Result :

```
[{"containerType":"Drive","testAtts":"{\"idNbr\":\"11111111111\",\"name\":\"ATTTT\"}"}]
```

Can anyone suggest a fix?

Comment: `jsonMap.put("testAtts", new JSONObject(testAttMap).toString());` - you're explicitly converting the object `toString`, it's unclear to me why that output is unexpected.

Comment: Use a String,Object map and Simply assign the `testAtts` key the value of the other map?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert hashmap to JSON object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155800/how-to-convert-hashmap-to-json-object-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is simply:

```
jsonMap.put("testAtts", new JSONObject(testAttMap));
```

instead of

```
jsonMap.put("testAtts", new JSONObject(testAttMap).toString());
```

the slashes are there because you are escaping the double quotes

Comment: not sure what you're talking about, why would it fail with string values

Comment: It wouldn't fail with string values (it won't error, just have an outcome other than the one the OP wants), but you're suggesting a `JSONObject` value. Did you actually try this?

Comment: `jsonMap` is declared as `HashMap<String,String> jsonMap` which is probably why OP called `toString()` on it.

Comment: I am not sure why it is downvoted. Removing `toString` call is right step. Other step required is changing type of `jsonMap` to something which can store as value string and other objects so `Map<String, Object>` comes to mind (since we don't want to use raw types).

Comment: I am not sure why people are saying Object is required instead of String in the map, all I see is these two calls `testAttMap.put("idNbr", "11111111111");
        testAttMap.put("name", "ATTTT");`

Comment: Because you're presumably looking at the inner object `testAttMap`, not the outer one `jsonMap`, which is also `HashMap<String,String>` but into which you're nonetheless trying to put a `JSONObject` value? That's just how types work.