# ObjectMapper using com.jsoniter library

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo, objectmapper

I have a `Map<String, Object> map` that was deserialized from a simple JSON string  `{"field1":"val1", "field2":"val2", "isReal":true}`. I am trying to construct a Java object `MyObject` with the above fields.

I can do it using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` like so:

```
public static MyObject load(Map<String, Object> map) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.readValue(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(map), MyObject.class);
    }
```

I was wondering if anyone knows how to do the same using `com.jsoniter` library?

I have tried to use `JsonIterator.deserialize`, but that doesn't take a `Map` as input.

I have also seen `ReflectionEncoderFactory` usage on the library website, but I don't fully grasp as to how I would use it to construct an object `MyObject`

Comment: What have you tried and what errors are you getting?

Comment: @ScaryWombat
I don't know what API to use to convert `Map<String, Object> map` to POJO using `com.jsoniter`. I know that `ObjectMapper` from `jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` works, but what would be the equivalent using `jsoniter` library?

Comment: Did you look at http://jsoniter.com/ ?  On the front page they have examples using `deserialize` - did you try this?

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I did, I don't understand how to use it... can you please explain?

Comment: why don't you post what you have tried?  It looks very similar in concept to jackson

Comment: @ScaryWombat
I only see how to `deserialize` a JSON string or bytes[] to an object or Iterator, I would like to `deserialize` a map to an object of class `MyObject`. I don't see a `deserialize` methods that takes a `Map<String, Object> map` as input.

Comment: @ScaryWombat
I've updated the question to say what I have tried, but I must be not understanding the examples at jsoniter.com because I wasn't able to construct an object like I can with jackson.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36934134/2310289)  Basically uou are wanting to convert a map to json with no dependancies (otherwise use jackson)

Comment: @ScaryWombat
I can convert it without dependencies, and I also know how to do it with jackson. My questions are:  1) Is it possible to do it with jsoniter? 2) How?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @ScaryWombat
I am also NOT trying to get a JSON string back, I am trying to map a `Map<String, Object> map` to an object using jsoniter library.

Comment: Is not the intermediate step `new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(map)` converting to json?  Once you have json you can use jsoniter to `deserialize` to your object - no?  Anyway, that is all I can add.

Comment: The equivalent would be:
`public static PulsarS3SourceConfig load(Map<String, Object> map) throws IOException {
        JsonStream.serialize(map);
        return JsonIterator.deserialize(JsonStream.serialize(map), PulsarS3SourceConfig.class);
    }`

Comment: @ScaryWombat
I don't need it twice, it was a typo. Yes, you have set me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per @Scary Wombat's explanation:

First it is necessary to convert the Map back to JSON string and then convert the JSON string to an object:

```
    public static MyObject load(Map<String, Object> map) throws IOException {
        return JsonIterator.deserialize(JsonStream.serialize(map), MyObject.class);
    }
```

`JsonStream.serialize(map)` is the same `new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(map)`