# JSON insert get automatically encoded into base64

Tags: java, mysql, json, jdbc, base64

I have a JSON object that I insert into my MySQL DB.

```
ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tableA(a, b, c, d_json)" +
                    " VALUES(?,?,?,cast(? AS JSON))", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
// some code
ps.setObject(4, jsonValue);
```

I insert a hashmap of string as :

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("key", "value");
    map.put("key1", "value1");
    map.put("key2", "value2");
```

However the json get encoded as following :

> '"base64:type15:rO0ABXNyABFqYXZhLnV0aWwuSGFzaE1hcAUH2sHDFmDRAwACRgAKRvckkACXRocmVz\naG9sZHhwP0AAAAAAAAx3CAAAABAAABnZhbHVlMXQABGtleTJ0AAZ2YWx1ZTJ0\nAANrZXl0AAV2YWx1ZXg="'

I would like to insert a string instead of this.
I saw some posts on S.O but I did not find any proper way to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks !

Comment: so `map` is your `json'Value`? The base64 you show in your posts contains a lot of unprintable bytes,  it's not a JSON representation of `map`

Comment: Yes it is. Indeed my issue is that even when I try to decode it using online tools it just returns something that does not have any sense.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155800/how-to-convert-hashmap-to-json-object-in-java) help?

Comment: Not that much since I use the sql method: cast as json. Actually I d like to not transform my data that much that s why I simply use an hashmap instead of a JSON object.

Comment: But it obviously doesn't work and I wonder how should SQL know how to cast a Java object to JSON.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I use MySQL

Comment: In the future, don't forget to tag your question, the database you're using is pretty important information for questions like this.

Comment: Got it, my bad.

Comment: Print out the values being fed into the MySQL call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly write Java object into MySQL - you need to convert your map to JSON string before writing it to table column.
According to official [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-values): "*Attempting to insert a value into a JSON column succeeds if the value is a valid JSON value, but fails if it is not*".

Here is an example (Jackson):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Test {

  private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

  public static String toJSON(Map<String, String> map) throws JsonProcessingException {
    return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(map);
  }
}
```

Another option would be to create one additional column, *e*, and then simply write map to two columns: `map(k,v) => d(k), e(v)`

Answer (score 1):

The Java Mysql Driver does not support automatic conversion of Hashmaps. In fact if you use an unkown type in `setObject`, it will use default Java Serialization to convert it to something it can handle. The database receives a byte array containing the serialized HashMap. The `cast(? as JSON)` converts that into something that can be stored in the column, which is the BASE64 encoded byte array.

You need to convert your HashMap to a **JSON String** in your Java code before sending it to the database.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering and explaining why it did not work. I accepted Piotr 's answer but yours is as good as his !