# count datas in three repositories and put them in a list or a map and convert it to json

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have three lists that holds the number of data in a database

```
List<Long> list1= list1Repo.countAll();
List<Long> list2= list2Repo.countAll();
List<Long> list3= list3Repo.countAll();
```

I want to combine these lists into one JSON object which supposed to be as follows:

```
[
  { label: "list1", value: 30 },
  { label: "list2", value: 25 },
  { label: "list3", value: 25 },
 
]
```

value is the counted numbers inside the lists.
How do i do this?

Comment: If I understand you correct, "list1Repo.countAll()" this is returning a number then why are you storing it into a List?

Comment: Yes , I am open to any suggestions. I don't have to store them in a list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert hashmap to JSON object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155800/how-to-convert-hashmap-to-json-object-in-java)

Comment: No actually, the main problem is that I need to count datas in three repositories and put them in a list or a map. Then I need to convert it to json, it solves the second part but not very helpful for the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your data like this in a Map:

```
Map<String, Long> listCountMap = new HashMap<>();
listCountMap.put("list1", list1Repo.countAll());
listCountMap.put("list2", list2Repo.countAll());
listCountMap.put("list3", list3Repo.countAll());
```

Then refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155800/how-to-convert-hashmap-to-json-object-in-java) to convert your map into a JSON object.