# convering a Map<Object, List<>> to JSON using gson library

Tags: java

I am trying to  convert a Map> to JSON using gson library. The issue is taht the String returned after converting is to JSON returns the hashcode of the Object but it is returning the list correct.

```
{"com.techm.kpn.servicecatalog.common.vo.xsd.Characteristic@61a86b":["C","C++","Java"],"com.techm.kpn.servicecatalog.common.vo.xsd.Characteristic@1780a05":["FreeCharge","Instagram","SnapChat","Twitter","Whatsapp"]}
```

and in the javascript I am not able to print out the properties of the Chracteristic object.

Here is the map i declared

```
Map<Characteristic, List<String>> variantCharacteristics = new HashMap<Characteristic, List<String>>();
```

and

```
String variantJson = new Gson().toJson(variantCharacteristics);
```

when I am printing above string var it is printing

```
{"com.techm.kpn.servicecatalog.common.vo.xsd.Characteristic@61a86b":["C","C++","Java"],"com.techm.kpn.servicecatalog.common.vo.xsd.Characteristic@1780a05":["FreeCharge","Instagram","SnapChat","Twitter","Whatsapp"]}
```

Comment: If you use `Object` as key, Then the GSON will use the `toString()` method to get the key. what value of Object are you expecting ?

Comment: Post your java code too.

Comment: do you have proper getter/setter in `Characteristic` class.

Comment: Implement the toString() method for your `Characteristic` class. Are you using Spring?

Comment: yes, gettters and setter are correct in the class @Braj

Answer (score 0):

Try using `enableComplexMapKeySerialization` if you want the Map Key to be serialized according to default Gson rules you can use [enableComplexMapKeySerialization](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#enableComplexMapKeySerialization()).

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization()
        .setPrettyPrinting().create();
```

[Relevant post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360836/gson-is-there-an-easier-way-to-serialize-a-map)

---

From the documentation of [enableComplexMapKeySerialization](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#enableComplexMapKeySerialization())

Enabling this feature will only change the serialized form if the map key is a complex type (i.e. non-primitive) in its serialized JSON form. The default implementation of map serialization uses `toString()` on the key; however, when this is called then one of the following cases apply:

**Maps as JSON objects**

For this case, assume that a type adapter is registered to serialize and deserialize some Point class, which contains an x and y coordinate, to/from the JSON Primitive string value "(x,y)". The Java map would then be serialized as a `JsonObject`.

Below is an example:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
   .register(Point.class, new MyPointTypeAdapter())
   .enableComplexMapKeySerialization()
   .create();

Map<Point, String> original = new LinkedHashMap<Point, String>();
original.put(new Point(5, 6), "a");
original.put(new Point(8, 8), "b");
System.out.println(gson.toJson(original, type));
```

The above code prints this JSON object:

```
{
 "(5,6)": "a",
 "(8,8)": "b"
}
```

---

By default Gson converts application classes to JSON using its built-in type adapters. If Gson's default JSON conversion isn't appropriate for a type, extend this class to customize the conversion. Here's an example of a type adapter for an (X,Y) coordinate point:

```
public class PointAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Point> {
 public Point read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
   if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
     reader.nextNull();
     return null;
   }
   String xy = reader.nextString();
   String[] parts = xy.split(",");
   int x = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
   int y = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
   return new Point(x, y);
 }
 public void write(JsonWriter writer, Point value) throws IOException {
   if (value == null) {
     writer.nullValue();
     return;
   }
   String xy = value.getX() + "," + value.getY();
   writer.value(xy);
 }
}
```

Read more about [GSON TypeAdapter](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html)

Comment: waht is this new MyPointTypeAdapter()) class for. I dont have MyCharacteristicTypeAdapter created.

Comment: here is the [reference](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) to read about it. updated the post also.